# Unexpected behavior of a value-type field marked readonly

Tags: c#

I have a similar situation to this one:

```
struct A
{
    string[] strs;

    public A(int cap) => strs = new string[cap];

    public void Set(int i, string s) => strs[i] = s;
}

class B
{
    readonly A a = new A(5);

    public void Set(int i, string s) => a.Set(i, s);
}
```

and I'm calling the `Set` method on class `B`, but the array in `a` is not changing, however, if I remove the `readonly` keyword the method works as intended and the array gets changed.

I realize `A` should be a class and not a struct, but I mainly just want to understand why this happens.

Comment: What makes you think it's not changing?

Comment: this doesn't repro for me; it works fine. Are you sure that in the *real* code, you aren't setting a *field* of `A`? I would expect *that* to fail in the way you suggest. Can you post something that actually shows the behaviour you're seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are reporting sounds like in your *real* code you're actually setting a *field* of `A` (the code in the question doesn't behave in the way claimed). For example, *this code* would fail in this way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.Set("abc");
        // writes "init" if readonly left in, "abc" otherwise
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }
}
struct A
{
    string _s;
    public A(int cap) => _s = "init";
    public void Set(string s) => _s = s;
    public override string ToString() => _s;
}

class B
{
    readonly A a = new A(5);
    public void Set(string s) => a.Set(s);
    public override string ToString() => a.ToString();
}
```

The reason for this is that with the `readonly`, the call to `a.Set()` is really:

```
var tmp = a;
tmp.Set(); // operates on a clone
```

which is precisely *because* it wants to guarantee the `readonly` part of the field declaration - as otherwise the call to `Set()` has had the side-effect of changing the value of the readonly field. To avoid this in the simplest way: avoid mutable structs! In recent C# versions (7.2+), you can declare structs as `readonly struct`, which will help you enforce this (it won't compile if you try to do anything dangerous *and* it allows the compiler to remove this extra clone step, and to use a more efficient implementation of the `in` ("ref readonly") modifier).